# Include tooltips to clustered bar chart in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have some code for a **clustered** bar chart below. Would anyone be able to tell me what to needs to be done to include tootips the below chart. Its a **clustered** (not stacked) bar chart.

```py
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("bar_stacked_grouped.html")

factors = [
    ("Q1", "jan"), ("Q1", "feb"), ("Q1", "mar"),
    ("Q2", "apr"), ("Q2", "may"), ("Q2", "jun"),
    ("Q3", "jul"), ("Q3", "aug"), ("Q3", "sep"),
    ("Q4", "oct"), ("Q4", "nov"), ("Q4", "dec"),

]

regions = ['east', 'west']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=factors,
    east=[ 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9 ],
    west=[ 5, 7, 9, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7 ],
))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250,
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(regions, x='x', width=0.9, alpha=0.5, color=["blue", "red"], source=source,
             legend=[value(x) for x in regions])

p.y_range.start = 0
p.y_range.end = 18
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_center"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

Thanks

Michael

Comment: what data you want to include in tooltips?

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you, you want to add tooltips:

so you could test something like:

reference-> [HoverTool and Tooltips](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool)

```
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(Q, east, west)", "([@x], @east, @west)"),
]

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")
```

[image]

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer !!

Answer (score 1):

You could show some data with the hover tools by adding these lines:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=factors,
    east=[ 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9 ],
    west=[ 5, 7, 9, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7 ],
))

tooltips = [
    ("x", "@x"),
    ("name", "$name"),
    ("value", "@$name")
]

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250,
           toolbar_location="left", tools="hover", tooltips = tooltips)
```

The hover variable `@$name` can be used to look up values from the stack column for each layer. For instance, if a user hovers over a stack glyph with the name "East", then `@$name` is equivalent to `@{East}`. Source: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#hover-tools